# Is LLVM's 'invoke' instruction a terminator, and if so, why not syntactically?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In the documentation[1], the `invoke` instruction is listed as a terminator instruction, but syntactically it is written as:

```
<result> = invoke [cconv] [ret attrs] <ty>|<fnty> <fnptrval>(<function args>) 
              [fn attrs] [operand bundles] to label <normal label> 
              unwind label <exception label>
```

And in the description it says it is like a `call` (which also binds a result).

Why is the instruction written this way if it is a terminator instruction, and is it ever possible to use that `<result>`? Indeed, will any instructions after an `invoke` ever be reachable?

In experimentation, it would seem that on a successful return, control flows to the `<normal label>`. Is there a special way of returning that instead returns control to the instruction after `invoke`?

And related to that, if control always passes to the `<normal label>`, is it possible to get access to the value that is returned (assuming not returning `void`) from the invoked function?

1. http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#terminator-instructions

Comment: Since you're reading the documentation anyway, why not check the lemma of `invoke` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple questions:

1. > Why is the instruction written this way if it is a terminator
   >   instruction?

It is written that way as a means to support exception processing. It is a short-hand (and extremely convenient) way to handle normal result flow or exception catching without a lot of additional machinery.

2. > is it ever possible to use that `<result>`?

In the basic block, which starts with the respective label, you should be able to access result. Are you getting an error when attempting to do so?

3. > Indeed, will any instructions after an invoke ever be reachable?

As it is a *terminating* instruction of a basic block then the general answer is ***no***. What typically follows is a label to something, either those setup in the `invoke` or some other branch/switch label.

4. > is it possible to get access to the value that is returned (assuming
   >   not returning void) from the invoked function?

This looks likes a repeat of question #2. So the same answer applies.

Comment: Ah -- my mistake was thinking that registers were only available within a single basic block (in which case, since the invoke is the last instruction, it wasn't clear how to use the result). Thanks!

Comment: @DanielPatterson - Yeah, the notion of 'scope' would have killed getting at the `result` otherwise. If you are generating LLVM-IR you have to consider that in your register naming convention(s).